# HTML: Best practice for POSTing empty/disabled form elements

Tags: html, forms

I have a form which is used as an interface for CRUD on database records.  Some of the elements on the form are interdependent, such that if one field has a value of X, then other fields should be made required and filled out by the user.

A simple example might be something like a personal info section:

```
<select name="relationship-status">
    <option value="single">Single</option>
    <option value="married">Married</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="spouse-first-name" />
<input type="text" name="spouse-last-name" />
```

...where the fields `spouse-first-name` and `spouse-last-name` would be required if `relationship-status` was set to `married`, and would be disabled (or hidden) otherwise.

My question is, in this example, when a person goes from married to single and wants to update their data as such, we also want to clear the spouse name values and post this back to the server so that the values are cleared in the database.  We can use JavaScript to clear the fields for them when they change to `single`, but if we disable the form elements so that they can't edit them, then they don't get POSTed when the form is submitted.

I can think of the following solutions:

- We could make them `readonly` instead of `disabled`, but that method only works for certain form controls (specifically, it does not work for other `select` elements), so this isn't an option.
- We could duplicate each of these fields as a `hidden` input that would be POSTed with the form, but not editable by the user, but this seems like such a hack.
- We could also enable the disabled fields right before submitting, and then re-disable them right afterwards.  This is the method I'm using right now, but I feel like I'm missing something, and there has to be a better way.

Is there something I'm not thinking of, or a more sensible way of accomplishing both:

1. Not allowing the user to edit a field, and
2. Allowing the field's value to be POSTed with the form, even if blank.

Comment: You should work to enforce the data validity on the server side. This means that when someone changes status to "single", the spouse name should be cleared by the server regardless of POST value.

Comment: Agreed.  Client-side validation is for the purpose of making a better UI.  *Server-side* validation is for the purpose of enforcing data integrity and business rules.

Comment: Thank you both, and I just may do that for other reasons; however, it doesn't really answer the question that I asked.  There are other scenarios where server validation would not help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the most robust and least kludgy solution is to use the `readonly` property for all elements except `<select>`.  For `<select>` elements, I just disable the `<option>` child elements *that aren't currently selected*.  This effectively prevents the user from changing the value.  I then color the `<select>` as though it were disabled with a gray background to complete the illusion.  At this point, all form elements will post with the form, even with no values, and regardless of whether they're "disabled" or not.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is, beside to make the validation in the client side, add in the javascript the function form.submit(), if someone disable the JS won't be able to submit the form, beside that agree with the others comments, add server validation.